# Having trouble on firebase fetching data and display in Textview......,

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been working on this code for several days,first I thought its database reference that has a problem,GetRef is working,so I am little bit confused because datasnap returns null....,It was actually working before I updated my database reference...,

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
            final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey");
            Log.d("inter", key);

            // Initialize Database
            Query queryRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("REPORTS").orderByKey()
                    .equalTo(key);

            String dd=queryRef.toString();
            Log.d("query", dd);

    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                @Override

                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getRef());

                    Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if (newPost != null) {
                        reportSingle = new FoodItem(newPost.get("MEAL_TITLE").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("DESCRIPTION").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("MEAL_INGREDIENTS").toString().trim(),

                                newPost.get("MEAL_PRICE").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("MEAL_CATEGORY").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("MEAL_QUANTITY").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("MEAL_NUTRITIONAL_VALUE").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("MEAL_TYPE").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("LOCATION").toString().trim(),
                                newPost.get("PICTURE").toString().trim(),
                                dataSnapshot.getRef(),
                                newPost.get("VOTES").toString().trim());


                        String s1 = reportSingle.getIngredients().trim();
                        Log.d("single", s1);
                        singleIngredients.setText(reportSingle.getIngredients());
                        singleQuantity.setText(reportSingle.getQuantity());
                        singleNutritionalValue.setText(reportSingle.getQuantity());
                        singleMealType.setText(reportSingle.getMeal_type());

                        singleLocation.setText(reportSingle.getLocation());
                        //singleInstitution.setText(reportSingle.getInstitution());

                        singleTitle.setText(reportSingle.getTitle());
                        singleDescription.setText(reportSingle.getDescription());


                        String photoBrew = reportSingle.getPicture();


                    }else{
                        Log.d("none", "none");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    // Getting Post failed, log a message##
                    String s=databaseError.toException().toString();
                    Log.d( "Post:Cancelled", s);

                    Toast.makeText(MealDetailsActivity.this, "Failed to load data.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
           }
```

Comment: try following the docs and using `dataSnapshot.children` to get individual reports. currently you are getting key value objects

Comment: Stack Overflow is a lousy mechanism for debugging your code, especially when there is so much of it. If you reduce your code to the minimum that is needed to reproduce your problem (a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it'll be much easier to help.

Comment: final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey"); working alright so I dont know if its the query or in getting data from datasnapshot