# Firebase Datasnapshot returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching data from a firebase child and mapping it to textviews to display to the user....,
    The firekey is alright and the query but on child added nothing seems to be returned..,
    It was alright before I changed from Firebase client to firebase database,nothing seems to be happenning at value event listener as its also jumping break points

```
singleLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleLocaton);
        //Added quantities
        singleIngredients = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleIngredients);
        singleQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleQuantity);
        singleNutritionalValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleNutritionalValue);
        singleMealType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleMealType);
        //Added quanitities
        singleTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleTitle);
        singleDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleDescription);
        imPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showSingleBrewImage);
        //singleVotes=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.singleVotes);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey");
        Log.d("inter", key);

        // Initialize Database
        Query myRef = mDatabase.child("REPORTS").orderByKey()
                .equalTo(key);
        myRef.keepSynced(true);


        String dd = myRef.toString();
        Log.d("query", dd);
        // Read from the database

// Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                if (newPost != null) {
                    SingleItem = new FoodItem(newPost.get("MEAL_TITLE").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("DESCRIPTION").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("MEAL_INGREDIENTS").toString().trim(),

                            newPost.get("MEAL_PRICE").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("MEAL_CATEGORY").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("MEAL_QUANTITY").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("MEAL_NUTRITIONAL_VALUE").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("MEAL_TYPE").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("LOCATION").toString().trim(),
                            newPost.get("PICTURE").toString().trim(),
                            dataSnapshot.getRef(),
                            newPost.get("VOTES").toString().trim());


                    String s1 = SingleItem.getIngredients().trim();
                    Log.d("single", s1);
                    singleIngredients.setText(SingleItem.getIngredients());
                    singleQuantity.setText(SingleItem.getQuantity());
                    singleNutritionalValue.setText(SingleItem.getQuantity());
                    singleMealType.setText(SingleItem.getMeal_type());

                    singleLocation.setText(SingleItem.getLocation());
                    //singleInstitution.setText(SingleItem.getInstitution());

                    singleTitle.setText(SingleItem.getTitle());
                    singleDescription.setText(SingleItem.getDescription());
```

Comment: you are simply posting your previous question again ?

Comment: Thought it was too long before,no good unswer

Comment: Add a listener for `.info/connected` to determine if your app is connected.  You can use [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) in the documentation.

Comment: Use the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) to confirm that the `FoodItems` stored at location `REPORTS` are what you expect and then use the console to modify the `FoodItem` stored with `key` to fire your listener.

Comment: @Shubhank do you have a link to that previous question? With that I'll close it. Vincent: don't re-post a question. If you didn't get a good answer yet, improve the original question. For example: there is way too much code here for us to digest quickly. Very likely you can also reproduce the problem with fewer than 8 properties. If you spend the effort to reduce the problem to a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is more likely that we'll be able to help.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752152/having-trouble-on-firebase-fetching-data-and-display-in-textview) is the one @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @qbix I think the query has the problem,I have confirmed its connected and the getRef is passing the key Ref well as I have log d and referred from the console.

Comment: So I think the issue is here   final String key = i.getExtras().getString("firekey");
            Log.d("inter", key);
            Query myRef = mDatabase.child("REPORTS").orderByKey()
                    .equalTo(key);